# Reference needed for Delta method

Tags: references, delta-method

I came to know from somewhere that  there is a technique called   delta method which can be  used to approximate the distribution of a function of a random variable using the distribution of the random variable itself and the first two moments of the function. It is often used in situations where the distribution of the function is difficult to derive directly, but the distribution of the random variable is known. Can someone kindly refer me to some links\books wherein this method is  discussed?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) discusses it, with references and further reading

Comment: Almost any advanced textbook that covers MLE or asymptotics will provide extensive details and examples.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me one such book of your choice

Comment: Look down at the bottom of the Wikipedia page for some references.

Comment: If you were to walk around stats departments and grab random people in the hallway, a lot of them would probably tell you to check out Casella Berger (https://mybiostats.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/casella-berger.pdf), specifically 5.5.4/page 240.

Answer (score 0):

George Casella and Roger L. Berger wrote the standard textbook for first-year statistical theory in graduate school: [*Statistical Inference*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126). Their book covers the delta method.